# asp.net(c#) copy user data from one table to another table using button click

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want copy data from from a detailsview(tableName=Jobs) to another table(tablename=Company) 
But it shows error like
Incorrect syntax near ')'
my code is as below:

```
     string apply = "INSERT INTO Company (JobTitle,CompanyName) select JobTitle,CompanyName from Jobs)";
```

i m using asp.net

Comment: You are updating your question , but not reading answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it, remove last`)`

```
 string apply = "INSERT INTO dbo.Company (JobTitle) select JobTitle from Jobs";
```

**UPDATE**
According to updated question.

```
string apply = "INSERT INTO Company (JobTitle,CompanyName) select JobTitle,CompanyName from Jobs";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string apply = "INSERT INTO dbo.Company (JobTitle) select JobTitle from Jobs)";
```

I hate to point out the obvious but you have an extra ')' at the end. :)

Comment: ok..this copies all data.Now i need to transfer a particular data using where clause..how can i do?

Comment: You will have to more specific, but something like this:

`string apply = "INSERT INTO dbo.Company (JobTitle) select    JobTitle from Jobs WHERE [EXPRESSION])";`

Expression could be something like: JobTitle = 'blah'